# Вопрос теоретический. Картинка или css код?

Tags: css, изображения, теория

Суть вопроса такова: как будет лучше для браузера, поисковика, кода и вообще в целом, как лучше вставлять мелкие элементы - как картинку или как css код? В качестве примера приведу такие фото с отзывов (но примеров может быть тысячи)

[image: Пример].

Здесь можно и элементарный код для border и box-shadow написать или же целиком вырезать и вставить как картинку.

Comment: Если у Вы делаете проект, который в перспективе будет расти. То можно предположительно рассчитать, сколько будут весить эти картинки, а сколько будет весить код. По вашему картинка будет больше весить? Или   Вам не важна скорость загрузки?

Comment: Это обычный лендинг для бизнеса. Проект расти не будет. Но нужно сделать всё красиво с большой скоростью загрузки.

Comment: Так проверьте сами, здесь работы на 5 мин.

Comment: Но мне не нужен конкретно этот пример. Я имею ввиду в целом, если на сайте будет 50 таких моментов, где можно вырезать и картинкой и чистым css написать. И так и так будет красиво выглядеть, но как лучше будет для скорости загрузки, браузера, поисковиков?

Answer (score 2):

Хорошим тоном в верстке сайта является `уменьшение объема графики`. Удалите ненужные изображения. Там, где это возможно, используйте текст вместо заведомо более тяжёлой графики.

Вы можете использовать одно масштабируемое изображение, но оно будет занимать много места и тормозить загрузку страницы. Лучше использовать несколько изображений, адаптированных под разные устройства, чтобы браузер загрузил нужное — это можно сделать при помощи плагина Imager. Он заменяет плейсхолдеры прозрачными изображениями, подтягивает к каждому атрибут src и назначает нужный размер, после чего вам остаётся только загрузить несколько вариантов изображения разных размеров.

Answer (score 0):

В данном примере стоит делать версткой.

Т.к. у вас фотография, обычный jpeg будет весить достаточно мало, jpg с такой рамкой потребует более высокого качества и будет больше весить + только 2+x. Плюс она будет на непрозрачном фоне, а png с фотографией будет весить уже в десятки раз больше.

Поэтому самый оптимальный вариант квадратная аватарка ~ 1.5x (для фотографии достаточное качество для ретины) + border-radius + рамка бордером.